# How do I pass a function result to pandas data frame using mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, function

I have a function which selects a list_id from a database and and returns the average time phone numbers from the list_id was called. where I am struggling is how to use this function to input into a dataframe or a data frame column. I want the script to iterate over a list of list_id's and return the average in a pandas dataframe

```
var = [8113,8114,8112]

def avg():
    for i in range (len(var)):
        mycursor.execute("SELECT list_id, avg(called_count) FROM list WHERE list_id ={}".format(var[i]))
        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
        for x in myresult:
            print(x[1])
avg()
```

If I use print(x) then it will return:

> (8113, Decimal('1.5814'))
> (8114, Decimal('0.0928'))
> (8112, Decimal('1.9127'))

If I just use  print(x[1]) then it will return just the result

> 1.5816
> 0.0934
> 1.9128

I am trying to pass the output to a dataframe with 2 columns being "list_id" and "result"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [pd.read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) for this. Also, it would be possible to run just one query, rather than one for each element in the list, which would be faster.

```
id_list_string = "','".join(var)
sql_query = f"SELECT list_id, avg(called_count) FROM list WHERE list_id IN ('{id_list_string}');"
df = pd.read_sql(
    sql=sql_query,
    con=mycursor
)
```

The above solution also uses [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

Comment: could you explain what the 'sql=sqlQuery,', does? is it an importable function?

Comment: @UltimateRoadman apologies, that should be `sql=sql_query`, will edit the answer now

Comment: I have trouble with  `con=mycursor` The error is an attribute error `AttributeError: 'MySQLCursor' object has no attribute 'cursor'`do you think its a problem relating to mysql.connector?

Comment: @UltimateRoadman, from the `pd.read_sql` documentation,  `con` takes "SQLAlchemy connectable, str, or sqlite3 connection". So you'll need to do `from sqlalchemy import create_engine` and then `cnx = create_engine("DB_CONNECTION_STRING_HERE")`

Comment: thanks, ill mark it as answered